# What exactly does "With a transaction, the second attempt fails atomically" mean?

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using GAE and I've found [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html#Uses_for_Transactions) about how to use transactions to handle two threads attempting to create an entity with the same key. Unfortunately, the documentation isn't clear about exactly how to detect the situation. It says "the second attempt fails atomically", but how? Does it throw an exception and if so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it raises `ConcurrentModificationException`. from your [docs link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html#Uses_for_Transactions), just after the first code block:

> This requires a transaction because the value may be updated by another user...If the entity is updated during the transaction, then the transaction fails with a ConcurrentModificationException. The application can repeat the transaction to use the new data.

Comment: That's the documentation for updating the data in an existing key. I suppose that since they dont say otherwise, the same exception is thrown when trying to create a new entity with the same key.

Comment: correct. transactions behave the same regardless of the type of write(s) they contain.